# Eclipse Java - For each line loop

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, foreach, readfile

I want to read a file, and I did it, but I want to read it line by line, beacuse after I read the file I need to do a "for each line loop". So far I did this:

```
File file = new File ("C:\\WebDrivers\\lex.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String serv= scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(serv);

    for(String sv : serv) {
        driver.findElement(By.className("inline-search")).sendKeys(sv);
    }
}
```

I get an error in the last "for loop", because I can only iterate over an array. How can I fix this?

Comment: You cannot iterate over a String. You need to use String.split to split String on linebreaks

Comment: Ok but where and how should I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write `for (String sv : serv.split("\n"))`. That will split the string into an array of lines that you can iterate over.

Comment: It wont split anything because `serv` is already a single line provided by `Scanner`

Comment: Then why are they iterating over it? I would have commented on their question to get clarification, but I need 50 rep.

Comment: I think OP will answer your question here so that will be able to fix your answer later. Probably each line has delimited items. But OP does not mention the details.